# Proof by Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, chinese-remainder-theorem

Prove (using Chinese remainder theorem) that a polynomial of degree $n$ (over the field of real numbers) can be uniquely determined from its values at the $n + 1$ point.

I can prove it by Lagrange polynomial or some simple principles - but I have to use the Chinese theorem, which usage in this proof isn't clear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_0,, a_1,\dots, a_n$ the $n+1$ points, and observe the remainder of the division of a polynomial $p$ by a linear polynomial$X-a_i$ is $p(a_i)$.

Consider the isomorphism of the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
\begin{align}
\mathbf R[X]\!\!\bigm/\!\bigl((X-a_0)(X-a_1)\dotsm(X-a_n)\bigr)&\longrightarrow\mathbf R[X]/(X-a_0)\times\mathbf R[X]/(X-a_1)\dotsm\mathbf R[X]/(X-a_n)\\
p\bmod(X-a_0)(X-a_1)\dotsm(X-a_n)&\longmapsto (p(a_0)\bmod X-a_0,\,p(a_1)\bmod X-a_1 ,\dots,p(a_n)\bmod X-a_n)
\end{align}
This isomorphism means that for each list of $n+1$ values $(\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\dots\alpha_n)$, there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $p(a_i)=\alpha_i$ for each $i=0,1,\dots, n\;$ (surjectivity), and this polynomial is unique up to a (polynomial) multiple of $(X-a_0)(X-a_1)\dotsm(X-a_n)\;$ (injectivity).

Now, as this modulus has degree $n+1$, the canonical representative of the congruence class of $p$, which is the remainder , has degree $\le n$.

*Note*: The solution does not not necessarily has degree $n$, depending on the relations between the lists  $(a_0,, a_1,\dots, a_n)$ and $(\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\dots\alpha_n)$.

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain 2 steps, which are not completely clear to me?  1 - shouldn't we write (p mod (X-a0)) or just p(a0) instead of (p(a0) mod (X-a0)) in the isomorphism? 2 - why do the isomorphism means that there exists such polynomial?

Comment: @SilverLight: For point 1, albeit it is represented by the number $p(a_0)$, there remains it is a congruence class, so $p\bmod(X-a_0)$ is just the same as $p(a_0)\bmod(X-a_0)$. For point 2, it is the surjectivity which implies the existence of such a $p$. Indeed any class $\bmod (X-a_i)$ is the class of the remainder, i.e. the class of a number $\alpha_i$. Thus surjectivity means that for any set of numbers $\alpha_i$, there exists a polynomial $p$ such that the remainder of $p\bmod(X-\alpha_i)=p(a_i)$, is precisely $\alpha_i$. Is it clearer?

Comment: Sure, thanks again!